# Windows Task Scheduler doesn't restart java app after failure

Tags: java, windows, taskscheduler

I have a java application that terminates with `System.exit(1);`. And I have created a task `"C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_221\bin\java.exe" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -jar C:\test\transfer-1.0.jar`. In the settings tab of Task Scheduler I have checked

- allow task to be run on demand,
- if the task fails, restart every 1 minute,
- attempt to restart up to 10 times,
- if the running task does not end when requested, force it to stop,
- stop the existing instance

But when I run the task it doesn't restart after 1 minute. The history logs say "Information: Action completed, and Task completed".

What I need to to so that the Task Scheduler restarts the java application?

Comment: You have tried to run your application directly and it works, right? ie from local environment - "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_221\bin\java.exe" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -jar C:\test\transfer-1.0.jar

Comment: Actually this app is working for some years. The only issue is that once there is no database connection it stops complitely, even if the database connection is back it doesn't run. I have to start it manually. I want Windows to restart the app if it detects an error.